# PHP Singly linked list, return array generated in external method

Tags: php, oop, linked-list

I have two classes, `LinkedList` and `Node`.

In both I have a function `printToArray()`. I would like to call this as demonstrated, and have it return an array.

In the `Node` class in printToArray(), you can see how I'm attempting to return the array. If I call, `var_dump($aNodeList)`, I can see the array is formed correctly, but its just not returning!

Would someone please mind explaining why this isn't working, or what I can go and read to find out.

From the following I would be expecting to see an array like such returned;

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "adam"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "andy"
}
```

n.b. I'm not sure what to call this post. If anyone can suggest an improvement please do.

Many Thanks

**Classes (excluding getters setters )**

```
class LinkedList{

    private $head;

    function __construct() {
        $this->head = null;
    }


    public function addNode($data){

        if( $this->head == null ){ 
            $this->head = new Node( $data ); 
        } else { 
            $this->head->addNode( new Node( $data ) ); 
        }

    }


    public function printToArray(){

        $aNodeList = array();

        try{

           // I expect the array to be returned here
           var_dump($this->head->printToArray($aNodeList) );

        } catch (exception $e){
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}


class Node{

    private $data = null;
    private $link;

    // Node constructor
    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->link = null;
    }

    public function nextNode(){

        if($this->link == null){
            throw new Exception("<span style=\"color:red\">Error..etc</span>\n\n");
        }
        return $this->link;
    }


    public function addNode($newNode){

        if($this->link == null){
            $this->link = $newNode;
        }else{
            $this->nextNode()->addNode($newNode);
        }

    }


    public function printToArray($aNodeList){

        $aNodeList[] = $this->data;

        if($this->link == null){

            return $aNodeList;
            exit;
        }

        $this->nextNode()->printToArray($aNodeList);

    }

}
```

**To init**

```
$oLinkList = new LinkedList;
$oLinkList->addNode('adam', null);
$oLinkList->addNode('andy', null);

var_dump($oLinkList);
```

Comment: you should write what errors you have 'not working' does not say much

Comment: thanks Robert have update my question. Been looking at it so long the output seemed obvious to me, sorry

Comment: You realise that PHP actually has a [built-in doubly-linked-list datastructure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) so no need to write your own singly-linked-list

Comment: cheers Mark, I'm trying to create this in an attempt to improve my understandign in oop. Struggling to understand why I cant return the array to the calling method, in LinkedList class